# Refresh Question

Tags: discussion

When I ask a question, it is typically answered quickly, however, this is not always the case. Sometimes, when I ask a question, it goes unanswered. I do not know what to do about this, because now, someone is unlikely to see my question. I know that I could place a bounty on it, but I do not have enough reputation to do that. Is there a way for me to "refresh" a question, like asking it again, to let everyone know I am still interested in an answer? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sit back and wait for the Community user to bump it?

Comment: @SomePerson I could, but I am afraid that that could happen very slowly, or never at all.

Comment: Wow, I never even saw the duplicate, even after looking around a fair amount.

Answer (score 2):

You could edit your question to add more information about your problem. This will 'bump' the question in recently-active lists, the home page, etc.

Do *not* do this excessively, or without a real improvement to the question. It's not a good idea to try to game the system that way - it's abuse and will be treated as such.